# How to generate all possible combinations of vectors without caring for order?

Tags: r

In a data frame, I have one column containing character strings. Let's say it looks like this:

```
x <- unique(df[,1])
x
"A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C"
```

I'd like to get all possible combinations of the unique character strings as sets of 2 without caring about their order, so `A, B` is the same as `B, A`, and I don't want to get same values as combination like `A, A`. So far, I got until this point:

```
comb <- expand.grid(x, x)
comb <- comb[which(comb[,1] != comb[,2]),]
```

But this still leaves the problem of having rows with the same combination of strings in a different order. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: `x` can't **possibly** be what you show; they would be unique if you had applied `unique()` to `df[,1]` would they not?

Comment: You're right, I mixed it up with printing the content of the data frame column itself. `x` of course doesn't contain duplicates.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's the `combn` function in the `utils` package:

```
t(combn(LETTERS[1:3],2))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "A"  "B" 
# [2,] "A"  "C" 
# [3,] "B"  "C"
```

I'm a little confused as to why your `x` has duplicated values.

Answer (score 13):

I think you are looking for `combn`:

```
x <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C")
combn(x,2)
```

Gives:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
[1,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "B"   "B"   "B"   "B"   "B"   "B"  
[2,] "A"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "C"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "C"  "B"   "B"   "C"   "B"   "C"   "C"
```

And if you want only unique values in `x` (I have no idea why you have duplicate values in `x` in the first place if it's the result of a `unique()` call):

```
> combn(unique(x),2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "A"  "B" 
[2,] "B"  "C"  "C"
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `combn`. I accepted the answer of BenBarnes because it gives exactly the output I wanted, but obviously you also answered my question.