# Non-redundant version of expand.grid

Tags: r, combinations, combinatorics, cartesian-product

The `R` function `expand.grid` returns all possible combination between the elements of supplied parameters. e.g.

```
> expand.grid(c("aa", "ab", "cc"), c("aa", "ab", "cc"))
  Var1 Var2
1   aa   aa
2   ab   aa
3   cc   aa
4   aa   ab
5   ab   ab
6   cc   ab
7   aa   cc
8   ab   cc
9   cc   cc
```

Do you know an efficient way to get directly (so without any row comparison after `expand.grid`) only the 'unique' combinations between the supplied vectors? The output will be

```
  Var1 Var2
1   aa   aa
2   ab   aa
3   cc   aa
5   ab   ab
6   cc   ab
9   cc   cc
```

**EDIT** the combination of each element with itself could be eventually discarded from the answer. I don't actually need it in my program even though (mathematically) `aa aa` would be one (regular) unique combination between one element of `Var1` and another of `var2`.

The solution needs to produce pairs of elements from both vectors (i.e. one from each of the input vectors - so that it could be applied to more than 2 inputs)

Comment: Isn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245213/how-to-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-vectors-without-caring-for-order) just the same question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate all possible combinations of vectors without caring for order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245213/how-to-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-vectors-without-caring-for-order)

Comment: I don't think so. That asks about elements from a single vectors. the accepted answers provides also a way to produce the combinations from elements of multiple inputs (2 or more)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

How about using `outer`? But this particular function concatenates them into one character string.

```
outer( c("aa", "ab", "cc"), c("aa", "ab", "cc") , "paste" )
#     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
#[1,] "aa aa" "aa ab" "aa cc"
#[2,] "ab aa" "ab ab" "ab cc"
#[3,] "cc aa" "cc ab" "cc cc"
```

You can also use `combn` on the unique elements of the two vectors if you don't want the repeating elements (e.g. `aa aa`)

```
vals <- c( c("aa", "ab", "cc"), c("aa", "ab", "cc") )
vals <- unique( vals )
combn( vals , 2 )
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "aa" "aa" "ab"
#[2,] "ab" "cc" "cc"
```

Comment: oh no, thanks. I need them separate to pass to other function. the previous was perfect! I actually realised I don't need `aa aa`, `bb bb` and `cc cc`. so if you re-edit back and I'll accept it :-)

Comment: Don't want to offend, but I don't see how this answer is the most upvoted accepted answer and continuing to get upvotes. Both approaches are incorrect. The first proposal with `outer` is nearly identical to `expand.grid`, it is just in a different format. It is also limited to only 2 inputs. For the 2nd approach, `combn` can only act on a single vector. If you have vectors with different elements the approach suggested here will give many incorrect results. Continuing...

Comment: The most extreme example is when we have disjoint vectors E.g. `v1 = 1:5, v2 = 6:10`. The correct solution should be isomorphic to `expand.grid(1:5, 6:10)`, which only has 25 results, however `combn(1:10, 2)` has 45 results. Again, I don't mean to offend, I just want to help to clarify for future users.

Comment: I have added an answer that addresses these concerns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68050873/4408538

Answer (score 26):

In base R, you can use this:

```
expand.grid.unique <- function(x, y, include.equals=FALSE)
{
    x <- unique(x)

    y <- unique(y)

    g <- function(i)
    {
        z <- setdiff(y, x[seq_len(i-include.equals)])

        if(length(z)) cbind(x[i], z, deparse.level=0)
    }

    do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(x), g))
}
```

Results:

```
> x <- c("aa", "ab", "cc")
> y <- c("aa", "ab", "cc")

> expand.grid.unique(x, y)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "aa" "ab"
[2,] "aa" "cc"
[3,] "ab" "cc"

> expand.grid.unique(x, y, include.equals=TRUE)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "aa" "aa"
[2,] "aa" "ab"
[3,] "aa" "cc"
[4,] "ab" "ab"
[5,] "ab" "cc"
[6,] "cc" "cc"
```

Comment: I note that it is missing a way to get the self-relationships included, but not the duplicate ones. For instance ("aa", "aa") is not a duplicate for it only appears only. In some cases, one wants the self-relationships too, but not the duplicates.

Answer (score 18):

If the two vectors are the same, there's the `combinations` function in the `gtools` package:

```
library(gtools)
combinations(n = 3, r = 2, v = c("aa", "ab", "cc"), repeats.allowed = TRUE)

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "aa" "aa"
# [2,] "aa" "ab"
# [3,] "aa" "cc"
# [4,] "ab" "ab"
# [5,] "ab" "cc"
# [6,] "cc" "cc"
```

And without `"aa" "aa"`, etc.

```
combinations(n = 3, r = 2, v = c("aa", "ab", "cc"), repeats.allowed = FALSE)
```

Comment: I note that repeats.allowed also removes the self-pairs such as ("aa", "aa"), which are not actually repeated. There is a missing middle way with this function.

Answer (score 16):

The previous answers were lacking a way to get a specific result, namely to keep the self-pairs but remove the ones with different orders. The **gtools** package has two functions for these purposes, `combinations` and `permutations`. [According to this website](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html):

- When the order doesn't matter, it is a Combination.
- When the order does matter it is a Permutation.

In both cases, we have the decision to make of whether repetitions are allowed or not, and correspondingly, both functions have a `repeats.allowed` argument, yielding 4 combinations (deliciously meta!). It's worth going over each of these. I simplified the vector to single letters for ease of understanding.

## Permutations with repetition

The most expansive option is to allow both self-relations and differently ordered options:

```
> permutations(n = 3, r = 2, repeats.allowed = T, v = c("a", "b", "c"))
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,] "a"  "a" 
 [2,] "a"  "b" 
 [3,] "a"  "c" 
 [4,] "b"  "a" 
 [5,] "b"  "b" 
 [6,] "b"  "c" 
 [7,] "c"  "a" 
 [8,] "c"  "b" 
 [9,] "c"  "c"
```

which gives us 9 options. This value can be found from the simple formula `n^r` i.e. `3^2=9`. This is [the Cartesian product/join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) for users familiar with SQL.

There are two ways to limit this: 1) remove self-relations (disallow repetitions), or 2) remove differently ordered options (i.e. combinations).

## Combinations with repetitions

If we want to remove differently ordered options, we use:

```
> combinations(n = 3, r = 2, repeats.allowed = T, v = c("a", "b", "c"))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "a" 
[2,] "a"  "b" 
[3,] "a"  "c" 
[4,] "b"  "b" 
[5,] "b"  "c" 
[6,] "c"  "c"
```

which gives us 6 options. The formula for this value is `(r+n-1)!/(r!*(n-1)!)` i.e. `(2+3-1)!/(2!*(3-1)!)=4!/(2*2!)=24/4=6`.

## Permutations without repetition

If instead we want to disallow repetitions, we use:

```
> permutations(n = 3, r = 2, repeats.allowed = F, v = c("a", "b", "c"))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "b" 
[2,] "a"  "c" 
[3,] "b"  "a" 
[4,] "b"  "c" 
[5,] "c"  "a" 
[6,] "c"  "b"
```

which also gives us 6 options, but different ones! The number of options is the same as above but it's a coincidence. The value can be found from the formula `n!/(n-r)!` i.e. `(3*2*1)/(3-2)!=6/1!=6`.

## Combinations without repetitions

The most limiting is when we want neither self-relations/repetitions or differently ordered options, in which case we use:

```
> combinations(n = 3, r = 2, repeats.allowed = F, v = c("a", "b", "c"))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "b" 
[2,] "a"  "c" 
[3,] "b"  "c"
```

which gives us only 3 options. The number of options can be calculated from the rather complex formula `n!/(r!(n-r)!)` i.e. `3*2*1/(2*1*(3-2)!)=6/(2*1!)=6/2=3`.

Answer (score 14):

Try:

```
factors <- c("a", "b", "c")

all.combos <- t(combn(factors,2))

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "b" 
[2,] "a"  "c" 
[3,] "b"  "c"
```

This will not include duplicates of each factor (e.g. "a" "a"), but you can add those on easily if needed.

```
dup.combos <- cbind(factors,factors)

     factors factors
[1,] "a"     "a"    
[2,] "b"     "b"    
[3,] "c"     "c"   

all.combos <- rbind(all.combos,dup.combos)

     factors factors
[1,] "a"     "b"    
[2,] "a"     "c"    
[3,] "b"     "c"    
[4,] "a"     "a"    
[5,] "b"     "b"    
[6,] "c"     "c"
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest and most direct method - doesn't require any additional packages and does what was asked for in 1 line.

Comment: @Ava - I agree. Was looking for the equivalent of `t(combn(1:nrow(df),2))` and there are a myriad of overcomplicated approaches IMO . This nails it in base R _and_ on one line.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a "greater than" operation to filter redundant combinations. This works with both numeric and character vectors.

```
> grid <- expand.grid(c("aa", "ab", "cc"), c("aa", "ab", "cc"), stringsAsFactors = F)
> grid[grid$Var1 >= grid$Var2, ]
  Var1 Var2
1   aa   aa
2   ab   aa
3   cc   aa
5   ab   ab
6   cc   ab
9   cc   cc
```

This shouldn't slow down your code too much. If you're expanding vectors containing larger elements (e.g. two lists of dataframes), I recommend using numeric indices that refer to the original vectors.

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

Use `comboGrid` from `RcppAlgos`:

```
library(RcppAlgos)
comboGrid(c("aa", "ab", "cc"), c("aa", "ab", "cc"))
     Var1 Var2
[1,] "aa" "aa"
[2,] "aa" "ab"
[3,] "aa" "cc"
[4,] "ab" "ab"
[5,] "ab" "cc"
[6,] "cc" "cc"
```

---

#### The Details

I recently came across this question [R - Expand Grid Without Duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68047141/4408538) and as I was searching for duplicates, I found this question. The question there isn't exactly a duplicate, as it is a bit more general and has additional restrictions which @Ferdinand.kraft shined some light on.

It should be noted that many of the solutions here make use of some sort of combination function. The `expand.grid` function returns the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) which is fundamentally different.

The Cartesian product operates on *multiple* objects which may or may not be the same. Generally speaking, combination functions are applied to a *single* vector. The same can be said about permutation functions.

Using combination/permutation functions will only produce comparable results to `expand.grid` if the vectors supplied are identical. As a very simple example, consider `v1 = 1:3, v2 = 2:4`.

With `expand.grid`, we see that rows 3 and 5 are duplicates:

```
expand.grid(1:3, 2:4)
  Var1 Var2
1    1    2
2    2    2
3    3    2
4    1    3
5    2    3
6    3    3
7    1    4
8    2    4
9    3    4
```

Using `combn` doesn't quite get us to the solution:

```
t(combn(unique(c(1:3, 2:4)), 2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    1    4
[4,]    2    3
[5,]    2    4
[6,]    3    4
```

And with repeats using `gtools`, we generate too many:

```
gtools::combinations(4, 2, v = unique(c(1:3, 2:4)), repeats.allowed = TRUE)
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    1    2
 [3,]    1    3
 [4,]    1    4
 [5,]    2    2
 [6,]    2    3
 [7,]    2    4
 [8,]    3    3
 [9,]    3    4
[10,]    4    4
```

In fact we generate results that are not even in the cartesian product (i.e. `expand.grid` solution).

We need a solution that creates the following:

```
     Var1 Var2
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    1    4
[4,]    2    2
[5,]    2    3
[6,]    2    4
[7,]    3    3
[8,]    3    4
```

I authored the package `RcppAlgos` and in the latest release `v2.4.3`, there is a function `comboGrid` which addresses this very problem. It is very general, flexible, and is fast.

First, to answer the specific question raised by the OP:

```
library(RcppAlgos)
comboGrid(c("aa", "ab", "cc"), c("aa", "ab", "cc"))
     Var1 Var2
[1,] "aa" "aa"
[2,] "aa" "ab"
[3,] "aa" "cc"
[4,] "ab" "ab"
[5,] "ab" "cc"
[6,] "cc" "cc"
```

And as, @Ferdinand.kraft points out, sometimes the output may need to have duplicates excluded in a given row. For that, we use `repetition = FALSE`:

```
comboGrid(c("aa", "ab", "cc"), c("aa", "ab", "cc"), repetition = FALSE)
     Var1 Var2
[1,] "aa" "ab"
[2,] "aa" "cc"
[3,] "ab" "cc"
```

`comboGrid` is also very general. It can be applied to multiple vectors:

```
comboGrid(rep(list(c("aa", "ab", "cc")), 3))
      Var1 Var2 Var3
 [1,] "aa" "aa" "aa"
 [2,] "aa" "aa" "ab"
 [3,] "aa" "aa" "cc"
 [4,] "aa" "ab" "ab"
 [5,] "aa" "ab" "cc"
 [6,] "aa" "cc" "cc"
 [7,] "ab" "ab" "ab"
 [8,] "ab" "ab" "cc"
 [9,] "ab" "cc" "cc"
[10,] "cc" "cc" "cc"
```

Doesn't need the vectors to be identical:

```
comboGrid(1:3, 2:4)
     Var1 Var2
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    1    4
[4,]    2    2
[5,]    2    3
[6,]    2    4
[7,]    3    3
[8,]    3    4
```

And can be applied to vectors of various types:

```
set.seed(123)
my_range <- 3:15
mixed_types <- list(
    int1 = sample(15, sample(my_range, 1)),
    int2 = sample(15, sample(my_range, 1)),
    char1 = sample(LETTERS, sample(my_range, 1)),
    char2 = sample(LETTERS, sample(my_range, 1))
)

dim(expand.grid(mixed_types))
[1] 1950    4

dim(comboGrid(mixed_types, repetition = FALSE))
[1] 1595    4

dim(comboGrid(mixed_types, repetition = TRUE))
[1] 1770    4
```

The algorithm employed avoids generating the entirety of the Cartesian product and subsequently removing dupes. Ultimately, we create a hash table using the [Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) along with deduplication as pointed out by [user2357112 supports Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica) in the answer to [Picking unordered combinations from pools with overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51886857/4408538). All of this together with the fact that it is written in `C++` means that it is fast and memory efficient:

```
pools = list(c(1, 10, 14, 6),
             c(7, 2, 4, 8, 3, 11, 12),
             c(11, 3, 13, 4, 15, 8, 6, 5),
             c(10, 1, 3, 2, 9, 5,  7),
             c(1, 5, 10, 3, 8, 14),
             c(15, 3, 7, 10, 4, 5, 8, 6),
             c(14, 9, 11, 15),
             c(7, 6, 13, 14, 10, 11, 9, 4),
             c(6,  3,  2, 14,  7, 12,  9),
             c(6, 11,  2,  5, 15,  7))
             
system.time(combCarts <- comboGrid(pools))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.929   0.062   0.992

nrow(combCarts)
[1] 1205740

## Small object created
print(object.size(combCarts), unit = "Mb")
92 Mb
  
system.time(cartProd <- expand.grid(pools))
   user  system elapsed 
  8.477   2.895  11.461 
  
prod(lengths(pools))
[1] 101154816

## Very large object created
print(object.size(cartProd), unit = "Mb")
7717.5 Mb
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a very ugly version that worked for me on a similar problem.

```
AHP_code = letters[1:10] 
 temp. <- expand.grid(AHP_code, AHP_code, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  temp. <- temp.[temp.$Var1 != temp.$Var2, ] # remove AA, BB, CC, etc. 
  temp.$combo <- NA 
  for(i in 1:nrow(temp.)){  # vectorizing this gave me weird results, loop worked fine. 
    temp.$combo[i] <- paste0(sort(as.character(temp.[i, 1:2])), collapse = "")
  }
  temp. <- temp.[!duplicated(temp.$combo),]
  temp.
```

Answer (score 0):

**USING SORT**

Just for fun, one can in principle also remove duplicates from `expand.grid` by combining `sort` and `unique`.

```
unique(t(apply(expand.grid(c("aa", "ab", "cc"), c("aa", "ab", "cc")), 1, sort)))
```

This gives:

```
    [,1] [,2]
[1,] "aa" "aa"
[2,] "aa" "ab"
[3,] "aa" "cc"
[4,] "ab" "ab"
[5,] "ab" "cc"
[6,] "cc" "cc"
```

Answer (score 0):

With repetitions (this won't work if you specify different vectors for different columns and for example values in the first column are always bigger than values in the second column):

```
> v=c("aa","ab","cc")
> e=expand.grid(v,v,stringsAsFactors=F)
> e[!apply(e,1,is.unsorted),]
  Var1 Var2
1   aa   aa
4   aa   ab
5   ab   ab
7   aa   cc
8   ab   cc
9   cc   cc
```

Without repetitions (this requires using the same vector for each column):

```
> t(combn(c("aa","ab","cc"),2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "aa" "ab"
[2,] "aa" "cc"
[3,] "ab" "cc"
```

With repetitions and with different vectors for different columns:

```
> e=expand.grid(letters[25:26],letters[1:3],letters[2:3],stringsAsFactors=F)
> e[!duplicated(t(apply(e,1,sort))),]
   Var1 Var2 Var3
1     y    a    b
2     z    a    b
3     y    b    b
4     z    b    b
5     y    c    b
6     z    c    b
7     y    a    c
8     z    a    c
11    y    c    c
12    z    c    c
```

Without repetitions and with different vectors for different columns:

```
> e=expand.grid(letters[25:26],letters[1:3],letters[2:3],stringsAsFactors=F)
> e=e[!duplicated(t(apply(e,1,sort))),]
> e[!apply(apply(e,1,duplicated),2,any),]
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    y    a    b
2    z    a    b
5    y    c    b
6    z    c    b
7    y    a    c
8    z    a    c
```