# Creating paired combinations from a list of products in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, combinations

I've got the data with users and products they used over a certain time period:

```
dframe <- data.frame(id = c(1234,1234, rep(3456, 4)), 
                     product = c("Apple", "Pear", "Apple", "Pear", "Grapes", "Kiwi"))

  id product
1234   Apple
1234    Pear
3456   Apple
3456    Pear
3456  Grapes
3456    Kiwi
```

I'm looking for a way of creating unique combinations of product pairs, per user (where pair x-y would equal y-x pair). The solution would look like this:

```
solution
  id product1 product2
1234    Apple     Pear
3456    Apple     Pear
3456    Apple   Grapes
3456    Apple     Kiwi
3456     Pear   Grapes
3456     Pear     Kiwi
3456   Grapes     Kiwi
```

Essentially, I'd like to apply an equivalent of `combn(product,2)` after dplyr's `group_by(id)`, if that makes sense. Any ideas how to approach this?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: That was a typo, now corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `group_by %>% do` with `combn`:

```
dframe %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% do({
    setNames(
        data.frame(t(combn(.$product, 2)), stringsAsFactors=F), 
    c("product1", "product2"))
})

#Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
#Groups: id [2]

#     id product1 product2
#  <dbl>    <chr>    <chr>
#1  1234    Apple     Pear
#2  3456    Apple     Pear
#3  3456    Apple   Grapes
#4  3456    Apple     Kiwi
#5  3456     Pear   Grapes
#6  3456     Pear     Kiwi
#7  3456   Grapes     Kiwi
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error when running your code: `Error in names(object) <- nm : 
  'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]`, any ideas where the problem is? thanks!

Comment: Did you use `t()` in front of `combn` to transpose the result?

Comment: I copy-pasted your code correctly, if that's what you're asking :)

Comment: @KasiaKulma Make sure your product is as.character

Comment: Yeah. I think @Sotos is right. I forgot to mention that I used `stringsAsFactors = F` when constructing the original data frame.

Comment: thanks, indeed, product was as.factor in my test set. Thanks a lot for that! Even though all solutions were relevant, yours I found most readable, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `CJ` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dframe)[, product := as.character(product)
     ][, CJ(product1= product, product2 = product, unique = TRUE), 
  by = id][product1 != product2
  ][!duplicated(data.table(id, pmin(product1, product2), pmax(product1, product2)))]
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, thanks for that, looks very promising, but the output I'm getting from it is duplicated pairs for 1234 id and only 4 options for 3456 id...

Comment: @KasiaKulma I get 7 rows based on it.

Comment: I get 6 with the following warning message: `Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(mmm, each) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(mmm, each) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors` Could that explain the discrepancies?

Comment: @KasiaKulma replace `product1=product` with `product1=as.character(product)` and the same with product2 in `CJ` and you will get the desired result.

Comment: @KasiaKulma  Sorry, I forgot to mention that I changed the class to `character`

Answer (score 2):

You can find a few functions [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171148/non-redundant-version-of-expand-grid) regarding unique combinations. If we borrow the function defined at that post by @Ferdinand.kraft

```
expand.grid.unique <- function(x, y, include.equals=FALSE)
{
    x <- unique(x)

    y <- unique(y)

    g <- function(i)
    {
        z <- setdiff(y, x[seq_len(i-include.equals)])

        if(length(z)) cbind(x[i], z, deparse.level=0)
    }

    do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(x), g))
}
```

Then we can use it via `dplyr` as follows,

```
library(dplyr)

 dframe %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   do(as.data.frame(expand.grid.unique(as.character(.$product), as.character(.$product))))

#Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
#Groups: id [2]

#     id     V1     V2
#  <dbl>  <chr>  <chr>
#1  1245  Apple   Pear
#2  3456  Apple   Pear
#3  3456  Apple Grapes
#4  3456  Apple   Kiwi
#5  3456   Pear Grapes
#6  3456   Pear   Kiwi
#7  3456 Grapes   Kiwi
```