# double sum calculation, what is the most efficient approach?

Tags: r, loops

I need to calculate this

[image]

where x is a vector of length n and f is a function.

What is the most efficient calculation for this in R?

One method is a double for loop, but that is obviously slow.

Comment: You can simplify it to just `sum^n_{i = 1} f(x_i, x_n)` since j \geq n and length(x) = n implies the inner sum is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

One fast way to do is the following:

Assume we have this vector:

```
x = c(0,1,2)
```

i.e. `n=3`, and assume f is a multiplication function:

Now, we use `expand.grid.unique` [custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171148/non-redundant-version-of-expand-grid) which produces unique combinations within vector; in other words, it is similar to `expand.grid` base function but with unique combinations:

```
expand.grid.unique <- function(x, y, include.equals=FALSE)
{
    x <- unique(x)

    y <- unique(y)

    g <- function(i)
    {
        z <- setdiff(y, x[seq_len(i-include.equals)])

        if(length(z)) cbind(x[i], z, deparse.level=0)
    }

    do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(x), g))
}
```

In our vector case, when we cal `expand.grid.unique(x,x)`, it produces the following result:

```
> expand.grid.unique(x,x)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    2
[3,]    1    2
```

Let's assign `two_by_two` to it:

```
two_by_two <- expand.grid.unique(x,x)
```

Since our function is assumed to be multiplication, then we need to calculate sum-product, i.e. *dot product* of first and second columns of `two_by_two`. For this we need `%*%` operator:

```
output <- two_by_two[,1] %*% two_by_two[,2]
> output
     [,1]
[1,]    2
```

Answer (score 2):

See `?combn`

```
x <- 0:2
combn(x, 2)

# unique combos
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    0    1
#[2,]    1    2    2

sum(combn(x, 2))
#[1] 6
```

`combn()` creates all the unique combinations. If you have a function that you want to sum, you can add a `FUN` to the call:

```
random_f <- function(x){x[1] + 2 * x[2]}

combn(x, 2, FUN = random_f)
#[1] 2 4 5

sum(combn(x, 2, FUN = random_f))
#[1] 11
```