# R - Expand Grid Without Duplicates

Tags: r, combinations, combinatorics, cartesian-product

I need a function similar to `expand.grid` but without the combinations of duplicate elements.

Here is a simplified version of my problem.

```
X1 = c("x","y","z")
X2 = c("A","B","C")
X3 = c("y","C","G")

d <- expand.grid(X1,X2,X3)

d
   Var1 Var2 Var3
1     x    A    y
2     y    A    y
3     z    A    y
4     x    B    y
.     .    .    .
.     .    .    .
.     .    .    .
23    y    B    G
24    z    B    G
25    x    C    G
26    y    C    G
27    z    C    G
```

`d` has 27 rows. But 6 of these contain duplicate values which I do not need Rows: 2, 5, 8, 16, 17 & 18

Is there a way to get the other 21 rows which does not contain any duplicates.

Note that vectors have more than 3 elements (`c("x","y","z","k","m"...)`, up to 50) and number of vectors is more than 3 in the real case. (`X4`, `X5`, `X6`... up to 11 ). Because of this expanded object is getting real large and RAM cannot handle it.

Comment: If I'm thinking about this right, you're trying to generate a grid containing 50^11 or 4.882813e+18 elements. I got R to give me an error message with 9 vectors of length 50 and it said can't allocate vector of size >7 PB. So, not surprised it doesn't fit in memory. Is there another way to think of this problem? Can you tell us what the range of your actual data is? If there's a very high probability of duplicates in any given row, we could build this up incrementally. But I don't think this will work if there aren't going to be tons duplicates.

Comment: Never mind my comment, use @joseph-wood's solution

Comment: @ngwalton, your comment above is spot on. Please don't remove it as it gets to the heart of this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **`RcppAlgos`<sup>*</sup>**, there is a function called `comboGrid` that does the trick:

```
library(RcppAlgos) ## as of v2.4.3
comboGrid(X1, X2, X3, repetition = F)
#      Var1 Var2 Var3
#  [1,] "x"  "A"  "C" 
#  [2,] "x"  "A"  "G" 
#  [3,] "x"  "A"  "y" 
#  [4,] "x"  "B"  "C" 
#  [5,] "x"  "B"  "G" 
#  [6,] "x"  "B"  "y" 
#  [7,] "x"  "C"  "G" 
#  [8,] "x"  "C"  "y" 
#  [9,] "y"  "A"  "C" 
# [10,] "y"  "A"  "G" 
# [11,] "y"  "B"  "C" 
# [12,] "y"  "B"  "G" 
# [13,] "y"  "C"  "G" 
# [14,] "z"  "A"  "C" 
# [15,] "z"  "A"  "G" 
# [16,] "z"  "A"  "y" 
# [17,] "z"  "B"  "C" 
# [18,] "z"  "B"  "G" 
# [19,] "z"  "B"  "y" 
# [20,] "z"  "C"  "G" 
# [21,] "z"  "C"  "y"
```

### Large Test

```
set.seed(42)
rnd_lst <- lapply(1:11, function(x) {
    sort(sample(LETTERS, sample(26, 1)))
})

## Number of results that expand.grid would return if your machine
## had enough memory... over 300 trillion!!!
prettyNum(prod(lengths(rnd_lst)), big.mark = ",")
# [1] "365,634,846,720"

exp_grd_test <- expand.grid(rnd_lst)
# Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)

system.time(cmb_grd_test <- comboGrid(rnd_lst, repetition=FALSE))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 9.866   0.330  10.196 

dim(cmb_grd_test)
# [1] 3036012      11

head(cmb_grd_test)
#     Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7 Var8 Var9 Var10 Var11
# [1,] "A"  "E"  "C"  "B"  "D"  "G"  "F"  "H"  "J"  "I"   "K"  
# [2,] "A"  "E"  "C"  "B"  "D"  "G"  "F"  "H"  "J"  "I"   "L"  
# [3,] "A"  "E"  "C"  "B"  "D"  "G"  "F"  "H"  "J"  "I"   "M"  
# [4,] "A"  "E"  "C"  "B"  "D"  "G"  "F"  "H"  "J"  "I"   "N"  
# [5,] "A"  "E"  "C"  "B"  "D"  "G"  "F"  "H"  "J"  "I"   "O"  
# [6,] "A"  "E"  "C"  "B"  "D"  "G"  "F"  "H"  "J"  "I"   "P"
```

**<sup>*</sup>** I am the author of `RcppAlgos`

Answer (score 2):

(Sorry, I just realized that your problem is as much a size problem, so removing them post-generation may not be feasible. For that, this may not be the best answer, but I'll keep it around for smaller-and-related questions.)

### base R

I hard-code "3", but you can use `ncol(d)` and/or `ncol(d)-1` for programmatic use.

```r
d[lengths(apply(d, 1, unique)) > 2, ]
#    Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1     x    A    y
# 3     z    A    y
# 4     x    B    y
# 6     z    B    y
# 7     x    C    y
# 9     z    C    y
# 10    x    A    C
# 11    y    A    C
# 12    z    A    C
# 13    x    B    C
# 14    y    B    C
# 15    z    B    C
# 19    x    A    G
# 20    y    A    G
# 21    z    A    G
# 22    x    B    G
# 23    y    B    G
# 24    z    B    G
# 25    x    C    G
# 26    y    C    G
# 27    z    C    G
```

(The row names are not reset, you can see the gaps to verify it is not 27 rows.)

And to verify, here are the rows with dupes:

```r
d[lengths(apply(d, 1, unique)) < 3, ]
#    Var1 Var2 Var3
# 2     y    A    y
# 5     y    B    y
# 8     y    C    y
# 16    x    C    C
# 17    y    C    C
# 18    z    C    C
```

Comment: I'm glad you answered, because I actually thought about your [`expand.grid` iterator](https://gist.github.com/r2evans/e5531cbab8cf421d14ed).

Comment: I haven't looked at (or used) that in a long time, thanks for reminding me! Yes, that might be useful here as well. Depending on how they intend to use it, that might be a factor as well ... we'll see what @Ex-StrConsultant thinks :-)