# How do I filter out combinations where the order doesn't matter?

Tags: r, combinations

I have a tibble of combinations of 1,2, and 3:

```
> tidyr::crossing(X1 = c(1,2,3), X2 = c(1,2,3))
# A tibble: 9 × 2
     X1    X2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     1     2
3     1     3
4     2     1
5     2     2
6     2     3
7     3     1
8     3     2
9     3     3
```

And I would like to filter out row 4, 6, 7, and 8 in this example, because the order does not matter. That is to say, (1, 2) is the same as (2, 1).

Is there a way to generate combinations like this, or filter out rows if a dataframe has already been generated?

Comment: Will vectors be the same every time, or are you asking more generally? For example, in your post `X1 = X2`, if this is always the case, you are using the wrong approach (i.e. generating the Cartesian product). All you need is combinations with repetition, which there are many packages that provide this functionality. See the canonical question for R here: [How to generate permutations and combinations in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22569176/4408538)

Comment: If instead you are asking more generally and each `X_i` could be different, then any approach provided thus far will become very inefficient very quickly as the sheer number of values to filter will become very large.

Comment: There is also this post [Non-redundant version of expand.grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17171148/4408538). You will see some of the same approaches posted here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `filter` rows where X1 is lower or equal than X2:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
crossing(X1 = c(1,2,3), X2 = c(1,2,3)) %>% 
  filter(X1 <= X2)

#      X1    X2
# 1     1     1
# 2     1     2
# 3     1     3
# 4     2     2
# 5     2     3
# 6     3     3
```

---

For a more generalized solution, check `gtools::combinations` with `repeats = TRUE`:

```r
gtools::combinations(3, 3, c(1, 2, 3), repeats = TRUE)

#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
#  [1,]    1    1    1
#  [2,]    1    1    2
#  [3,]    1    1    3
#  [4,]    1    2    2
#  [5,]    1    2    3
#  [6,]    1    3    3
#  [7,]    2    2    2
#  [8,]    2    2    3
#  [9,]    2    3    3
# [10,]    3    3    3
```

Or with `is.unsorted` `rowwise`:

```r
crossing(X1 = c(1,2,3), X2 = c(1,2,3), X3 = c(1,2,3)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(!is.unsorted(across(X1:X3)))
```

Made simpler in base R:

```r
df <- expand.grid(X1 = c(1,2,3), X2 = c(1,2,3), X3 = c(1,2,3))
df[!apply(df, 1, is.unsorted), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can combine the `min` and `max` values of the two columns together, then `slice` one entry out.

This works for both numeric and character columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(tmp = paste0(pmin(X1, X2), pmax(X1, X2))) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 1, by = tmp) %>% 
  select(-tmp)

# A tibble: 6 × 2
     X1    X2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     1     2
3     1     3
4     2     2
5     2     3
6     3     3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat the vector twice and use `combn`:

```r
unique(t(combn(rep(1:3, each = 2), 2)))

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    1    2
# [3,]    1    3
# [4,]    2    2
# [5,]    2    3
# [6,]    3    3
```

Note that the repeated vector passed into `combn` must be increasing, i.e. you have to set `each = 2` rather than `times = 2`; otherwise,

```r
unique(t(combn(rep(1:3, times = 2), 2)))

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    1    3
# [3,]    1    1
# [4,]    2    3
# [5,]    2    1
# [6,]    2    2
# [7,]    3    1
# [8,]    3    2
# [9,]    3    3
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this trick applies to your case

```
x <- 1:3
data.frame(
  X1 = rep(x, rev(seq_along(x))),
  X2 = sequence(rev(seq_along(x)), x)
)
```

which gives

```
  X1 X2
1  1  1
2  1  2
3  1  3
4  2  2
5  2  3
6  3  3
```