# Add rows with possible combinations in R dataframe

Tags: r, combinatorics

*First of all, please accept my apology for a poor title - i'm sure there could a better one, but I lack proper English / math terminology to phrase it the right way.
I'm also pretty sure my problem is rather easy, but due to some basic math ignorance I don't even know how to call a decent google search.*

I'm trying to find all possible combinations of items within pairs of columns.

Given a data frame like this:

```
data.frame(obj1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
           obj2 = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "A"),
           obj3 = c("C", "D", "E", "F", "A", "B"),
           obj4 = c("D", "E", "F", "A", "B", "C"),
           obj5 = c("E", "F", "A", "B", "C", "D"),
           obj6 = c("F", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))

  obj1 obj2 obj3 obj4 obj5 obj6
1    A    B    C    D    E    F
2    B    C    D    E    F    A
3    C    D    E    F    A    B
4    D    E    F    A    B    C
5    E    F    A    B    C    D
6    F    A    B    C    D    E
```

I'd like to add new rows in a way that for every pair of columns (`obj1`-`obj2`, `obj1`-`obj3`, `obj1`-`obj4`, ..., `obj5`-`obj6`) all combinations of items appear.

For example: in the 1st column pair: `obj1`-`obj2`, item `A` appears only with item `B` and `F`. Other item level combinations are missing and that's what I want to get.

**Caveats**:
-each item (A,...,F) can appear only once within each row of the dataframe
-same letter pairs (of A-B and B-A) are treated as duplicates within a row, but not within a column

Effectively I'd like to grow this dataframe rowwise so that when a random pair of columns is picked, every combination of 6 items is present.

My gut tells me, that I'm looking at a 90 x 6 sized dataframe, but that's just intuition that i'm not able to put in a formula and explain how I came up with this number :)

*If my question is not clear, the answer is obvious or in any other way violates any rule, please let me know, so I can try to explain myself*

**EDIT**
After receiving all the comments i'll try to explain myself more clearly.

Consider this simple table of experimental conditions, let's call it **table1** and treat it as a between subject table:

[image]

In this, simpler case, each participant will be presented with 6 pairs of target-items (A, B, C) taken from columns (col1, col2, col3) in the following way (**table2** - within subject table):

[image]

Those 6 trials guarantee that for **every participant within each pair** every combination of target-items is present.

If I where to present 6 different traits (one per trial from table2) in a fixed order (for example: happy, sad, smart, bored, confused, tired) for every participant, after 3 participant each trait would be presented with regards to every combination of target-items.
For participant 1 - trait happy would be presented with targets A - B
For particiapnt 2 - trait happy would be presented with targets B - C
For particiapnt 3 - trait happy would be presented with targets C - A
**NOTE** that a (theoretical) set of B - A would be considered a duplicate.

What I'm looking for is a way of extending **table1** from the above example of 3 items, into a 6 item **table1**.
Naturally **table2** will grow as well, but that's taken care of.
**Table1** is what is causing me problems.

This is how a starting point could look like

[image]

Thank you for any help.
Best regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/11095992/3358272

Comment: I found that question prior to posting but didn't know how to use the solutions that are provided - specifcally - how to deal with duplicates

Comment: What about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171148/non-redundant-version-of-expand-grid

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245213/how-to-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-vectors-without-caring-for-order There are a lot of pseudo- or real duplicates that may be worth looking at

Comment: `do.call(rbind, combinat::permn(letters[1:3]))` is a good example. (`expand.grid` gives all combinations, not permutations, so it will require specific post-generation filtering. If you had two or perhaps three columns, it might suffice, but more than that and it becomes a little overkill to generate and discard that much.)

Comment: @HFBrowning, r2evans I think none of those answer does what I'm looking for. For example, combinat::permn will give all possibilities (no caveats taken into account). This is something I could do by hand to simply set up all the conditions. Here I'm specifically looking for unique items within each pair given the structure provided.

Comment: To be clear, the second caveat means that if we have `A-B-C-D-E-F`, all examples with swaps like `B-A-C-D-EF`, `A-B-D-C-E-F`, even `B-A-D-C-F-E` should all not be present in the final output? What about swapping non-neighbour columns, like `C-B-A-D-E-F`?It's not clear what the expected output is to me now

Comment: ok, reading again I think you need to try to define this a little more carefully, perhaps use fewer letters/columns and give an exact description of what would and wouldn't be a duplicate. you say "when a random pair of columns is picked, every combination of 6 items is present." So each of the 15 pairs columns must have each of the `15` combinations of different letters in it. That doesn't really make it obvious what a duplicate is, because whether or not a row contributes to that condition depends on all the other rows!

Comment: Thanks Calum, I'll edit my question today and describe it in my usage context more carefully

Comment: @CalumYou I did my best with the edit and a simpler example. Is that more more clear now?

Comment: First, this isn't really a programming question in R or any other language.  I *think* I understand what you're trying to do, but it's not something that programming is going to solve for you - you actually need to work through the combinations.  Are ``A B C D E F`` and ``A B D E F C`` both valid or not?  As I understood it before, they would be two valid combinations - but as you're explaining it now, it seems that they may not be.  In terms of combinatorics, you have 6 options for your first position and 5 options for your 2nd position - for 30 options total.  Anything else will be repeats.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this again, consider the following start positions, which can be used to generate 6 combinations, as shown in the answer by Maurits Evers.

```
A B C D E F
A C E B D F
A E D C B F
A D B E C F
```

This family is generated by taking positions 1 3 5 2 4 6 of the previous spot.   With all the shifts, this is 24 different orderings.

You can generate 24 more in a similar fashion by starting with

```
F E D C B A
```

I'm pretty sure we can get another by

```
A B C E F D
```

which probably means that the following are also good:

```
A C F B E D
A F E C B D
A E B F C D
```

(and likewise for all the `F -> A` ones.

That makes 96.  Did I miss any or duplicate any?

Comment: (after posting this, I saw the caveats you're after - I'm working on a modification now)

Comment: Mellisa, thanks. If you can find a solution with respect to caveats it will be great help to me.

Comment: That update is done.  It's not really a programming question at this point - I came up with 96 combinations which should meet your requirements.  I do not know if there are others - I was systematic, but this isn't my area.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I looked at the answer from my mobile. Will inspect it closer when I arrive to my office. Thank you

Comment: Apologies, but I'm having some troubles in replicating the logic of what you described. Any chance you could make it more explicit? If you can, have a look at the edited part of my question

Answer (score 1):

**Note: I am unsure about what you're after. My answer does not seem to address your question, however I will leave it up because of the reference in @MelissaKey's answer.**

1. Define a shift function that circularly shifts entries of a numeric vector by `n` to the left

   ```
   shift <- function(x, n = 1) {
     if (n == 0) x else c(tail(x, -n), head(x, n))
   }
   ```
2. If we now start from an initial vector `v` which corresponds to the first row of your expected output `data.frame`

   ```
   v <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
   ```

   we can reproduce your expected output by `rbind`ing successively shifted versions of `v`

   ```
   do.call(rbind, lapply(0:(length(v) - 1), function(i) shift(v, i)))
   #    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
   #[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"
   #[2,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "A"
   #[3,] "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "A"  "B"
   #[4,] "D"  "E"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "C"
   #[5,] "E"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
   #[6,] "F"  "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"
   ```

This will work for any initial vector of any length `k`, producing a final `matrix` of dimension `k x k`.

Comment: it's not OP's expected output

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Hmm. Isn't the `data.frame` the output OP wants to reconstruct?

Comment: not as i understand it, OP gives this df as a starting point and explains afterwards what's missing in it.

Comment: As pointed out by Moody_Mudskipper I'd like to grow this example with subsequent rows. Thank you for you time though