# Remove all rows containing the same elements from dataframe, even though elements are in different order in R

Tags: r, dplyr, combinations

Here is my data:

```
mymat <- structure(c(3, 6, 9, 9, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 6, 6, 4, 1, 4), .Dim = c(7L, 2L))
```

Some rows are duplicated, several other rows contain the same elements although they are differentially ordered. I wish to remove all rows that contain the same elements, whether these elements are in the same (duplicated rows) or different order. This will retain only the first row of `c(3, 5)`.

I checked previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171148/non-redundant-version-of-expand-grid) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245213/how-to-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-vectors-without-caring-for-order). However, my requirement is that all such rows are removed rather than leaving one such row.

My question is also different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763216/how-can-i-remove-all-duplicates-so-that-none-are-left-in-a-data-frame) which removes all duplicated rows in that I look for rows not just duplicated, but also those that contain the same set of elements that are ordered differently. For example, rows `c(6, 9)` and `c(9, 6)` should both be removed since they both contian the same set of elements.

I look for solutions not using for loop since my real data is large and for loop may be slow.

Note: My full data has 40k rows and 2 columns.

Comment: Is your full data only two columns? Or many?

Comment: My full data has 40k rows and 2 columns.

Comment: This only removes duplicated rows. I wish to remove rows as long as they contain the same elements, even if the rows are not duplicated. For example, rows `c(6, 9)` and `c(9, 6)` should both be removed since they both contian the same set of elements.

Comment: Your data is a `matrix` yet you tagged [tag:dplyr] (which does not operate on matrices), is there something else here?

Comment: I tag dplyr since I wonder there may be some handy functions there. If indeed, I could simply transform my data from matrix to dataframe.

Comment: @mnist, I don't agree with the duplicate tag. The post linked to the duplicate tag doesn't address the ordering problem, which is why the OP posted a new problem. See "My question is also different from this one..." in the original post.

Comment: Thank you @jblood94. I totally agree with you.

Comment: Are your data all integer values?

Comment: Yes, all are integers.

Comment: @Patrick, I'd have posted this as an answer if the question weren't closed:
`m <- rowSums(1/mymat)`; 
`mymatNoDup <- mymat[!(duplicated(m) | duplicated(m, fromLast = TRUE)),]`
It's about 2 orders of magnitude faster than any posted answer. It works for positive integers, but if you have zeros/negatives, just add to `mymat` when inverting.

Comment: @Patrick, sorry, that should have been `m <- rowSums(mymat + 1/mymat)`. Any binary symmetric pairing function would work. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3162166/what-function-symmetric-and-has-unique-solution for another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a little data to show that the matrix format remains

```
mymat <- structure(c(3, 6, 9, 9, 1, 4, 1, 10, 12, 13, 14, 5, 9, 6, 6, 4, 1, 4, 11, 13, 12, 15), .Dim = c(11L, 2L))

dup <- duplicated(rbind(mymat, mymat[, c(2, 1)]))
dup_fromLast <- duplicated(rbind(mymat, mymat[, c(2, 1)]), fromLast = TRUE)

mymat_duprm <- mymat[!(dup_fromLast | dup)[1:(length(dup) / 2)], ]

mymat_duprm
```

Comment: This will drop unique rows with repeated values. Try, e.g., `mymat <- matrix(c(1,3,2,3), nrow = 2)`

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the data rowwise and use `duplicated` -

```
tmp <- t(apply(mymat, 1, sort))
tmp[!(duplicated(tmp) | duplicated(tmp, fromLast = TRUE)), , drop = FALSE]

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    5
```

Answer (score 1):

As a matrix:

```r
tmp <- apply(mymat, 1, function(z) toString(sort(z)))
mymat[ave(tmp, tmp, FUN = length) == "1",, drop = FALSE]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    3    5
```

The `drop=FALSE` is required only because (at least with this sample data) the filtering results in one row. While I doubt your real data (with 40k rows) would reduce to this, I recommend you keep it in there anyway ("just in case", and it's just defensive programming).

Answer (score 1):

Benchmarking a couple new solutions along with a few already posted:

```
library(Rfast)
library(microbenchmark)

mymat <- matrix(sample(100, 4000, replace = TRUE), nrow = 2000)

noDup <- function(m) {
  return(!(duplicated(m) | duplicated(m, fromLast = TRUE)))
}

combounique1 <- function(m) {
  return(m[noDup(rowSort(m)),])
}

combounique2 <- function(m) {
  msum <- rowsums(m)
  return(m[noDup(rowsums(m^2) + msum + (msum - 3)*abs(m[,1] - m[,2])),])
}

combounique3 <- function(m) {
  return(m[noDup(rowsums(m + 1/m)),])
}

combounique4 <- function(m) {
  # similar to Harrison Jones, but correct
  return(m[noDup(rbind(m, m[m[,1] != m[,2], 2:1]))[1:nrow(m)],])
}

combounique5 <- function(m) {
  # similar to Ronak Shah, but maintains ordering within rows
  tmp <- t(apply(m, 1, sort))
  return(m[noDup(tmp),])
}

r2evans <- function(m) {
  tmp <- apply(m, 1, function(z) toString(sort(z)))
  return(m[ave(tmp, tmp, FUN = length) == "1",, drop = FALSE])
}

microbenchmark(mymat1 <- combounique1(mymat),
               mymat2 <- combounique2(mymat),
               mymat3 <- combounique3(mymat),
               mymat4 <- combounique4(mymat),
               mymat5 <- combounique5(mymat),
               mymat6 <- r2evans(mymat))

                          expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 mymat1 <- combounique1(mymat)  7129.9  7642.30  9236.841  8205.45  9467.70  28363.7   100
 mymat2 <- combounique2(mymat)   171.0   197.30   219.341   215.75   225.45    385.5   100
 mymat3 <- combounique3(mymat)   144.2   166.95   187.340   182.50   192.30    306.7   100
 mymat4 <- combounique4(mymat) 14263.1 15343.90 17938.061 16417.30 19043.30  34884.9   100
 mymat5 <- combounique5(mymat) 48230.9 50773.75 57662.463 55041.90 60968.35 193804.2   100
      mymat6 <- r2evans(mymat) 66180.3 70835.30 78642.552 77299.85 81992.60 161034.5   100

> all(sapply(list(mymat1, mymat2, mymat3, mymat4, mymat5, mymat6), FUN = identical, mymat1))
[1] TRUE
```

Note that `combounique2` and `combounique3` are only strictly correct for integer values. The idea is to use a symmetric pairing function to get a unique value for each pair of integers, then use `duplicated` on that.
(see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3162166/what-function-symmetric-and-has-unique-solution)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use, the following line of code:

```
mymat <- mymat[!mymat[,1] %in% mymat[,2], , drop = FALSE]
```

output:

```r
mymat
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    3    5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>